# The ADO.NET provider with invariant name 'System.Data.SqlClient' is either not registered

Tags: c#, entity-framework, azure, .net-core

I have a .NET Core React Web application that calls into a Class Library with a reference to the Entity Framework. I'm using a database that is stored in Azure, and every time I query my database, I get this exception:

> System.ArgumentException: 'The ADO.NET provider with invariant name 'System.Data.SqlClient' is either not registered in the machine or application config file, or could not be loaded. See the inner exception for details.'
>
> InnerException: ArgumentException: The specified invariant name 'System.Data.SqlClient' wasn't found in the list of registered .NET Data Providers.

I'm thinking I don't have something configured properly in my Web.config/App.config files but I'm not sure.

`Web.config` file in my web app:

```
<configuration>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="JATEntities" 
             connectionString="Server=tcp:[someserver].database.windows.net,1433;Database=JAT;persist security info=True;user id=[userid];password=[password];MultipleActiveResultSets=True;" 
             providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

My `App.Config` in my class library:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    </configSections>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="JATEntities"  
             connectionString="Server=tcp:[someserver].database.windows.net,1433;Database=JAT;persist security info=True;user id=[userid];password=[password];MultipleActiveResultSets=True;"
             providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    </connectionStrings>
    <entityFramework>
        <providers>
            <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" 
                      type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
        </providers>
    </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

Here's the code that I'm calling in my class library:

```
public class MyClass 
{
    // I've tried this as it seems to have worked for some people
    private static string __hack = typeof(SqlProviderServices).ToString();

    public void MyMethod()
    {
        using (var context = new JATEntities())
        {
            var query = from listing in context.CurrentListings
                        where listing.Id == id
                        select listing;
        }
    }
}
```

I've also referenced the App.config file from my ClassLibrary into my Web App project, but that doesn't seem to help.

```
[External Code]
JAT.DB.dll!JAT.DB.Repo.Repo.GetCurrentListingById(int id) Line 22
    at C:\Users\Jungle\source\repos\JAT\JAT.DB\Repo\Repo.cs(22)
JAT.Client.dll!JAT.Client.Controllers.SearchController.FirstMethod() Line 25
    at C:\Users\Jungle\source\repos\JAT\JAT.Client\Controllers\SearchController.cs(25)

[External Code]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What worked for me was upgrading to Visual Studio 2019, and creating a new .Net core web application and .net core class library and then moving all my code from my old solution into the new one.